# From TYPO3 DB wrapper to doctrine. Select Statement

Tags: php, sql, doctrine, typo3

I have to migrate some code from the TYPO3 DB wrapper to Doctrine with the QueryBuilder. In my database are four entries.

The original statement:

```
        $statementToMigrate = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTgetRows(
            'job_id,uid,pid,hash',
            'tx_test',
            'deleted = 0',
            null,
            null,
            null,
            'job_id'
        );
```

And my QueryBuilder version:

```
        $table = 'tx_test';
        $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)
            ->getQueryBuilderForTable($table);

        $sql = $queryBuilder
            ->select(
                "job_id,uid,pid,hash"
            )
            ->from($table)
            ->where(
                $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('deleted', 0)
            )
            ->execute()
            ->fetchAll();
```

The original statement provides me all four entries.
The new version only two. Where are the differences?
And how can I set " $uidIndexField= ''" in doctrine?

Solution:
I added

```
            $queryBuilder
            ->getRestrictions()
            ->removeByType(StartTimeRestriction::class)
            ->removeByType(EndTimeRestriction::class);
```

and now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi the Querybuilder takes into account the common "restrictions" like start/end date, language, hidden/ deleted. i guess you records are filtered out by some other restrictions.

see here for more about restrictions: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/RestrictionBuilder/Index.html#database-restriction-builder

Comment: to see all of this restrictions, you can check the query with: `$queryBuilder->getSQL()`. 
That should give you something like:

    SELECT 'job_id,uid,pid,hash' FROM `tx_test` WHERE (`tx_test`.`deleted` = 0) AND (`tx_test`.`hidden` = 0) AND (`tx_test.`starttime` <= 1563172920) AND ((`tx_test.`endtime` = 0) OR (`tx_test`.`endtime` > 1563172920));

Answer (score 1):

> And how can I set " $uidIndexField= ''" in doctrine?

Doctrine doesn't have such functionality by itself, afaik. Earlier in old Typo3 in the exec_SELECTgetRows method the array was simply traversed to set that index before return. Now it seems you have to do the same on your own. I searched for quite a long time to find good, fast and hopefully native way to achieve that effect with no luck, but finally I stumbled upon that snip:

```
...
// return $preparedStatement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = $preparedStatement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return array_column($result, null, $uidIndexField);
```

and finally it looks like that does the trick.